# How many random samples needed to pick all elements of set?

Tags: probability, random, coupon-collector

If repeatedly picking a random element from a set, what is the expected number of times I'd have to pick before seeing all the elements of the set?

Edit: when picking an element, it is simply counted and not removed from the set, so it can be picked again.

Comment: If you can see only by picking the elements, shouldn't the expected number be the carnality of the set?

Comment: (Assuming you meant cardinality). No, I forgot to mention that the elements are not removed from the set when picked, they are only counted.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Is the set finite?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about finite sets, right? Is there a particular distribution to how "random" works?

Comment: I guess for infinite sets the answer is trivial unless you don't distinguish infinite cardinalities.

Comment: Asaf Karagila, the definition of random is defined by the behavior of my system's PRNG, which I assume to be close to uniform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  The expected number of picks required to choose all the elements of the set is $$nH_n = n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For more details about this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4503130/25554