# Estimate the number of elements by random sampling with replacement

Tags: probability

### Setup:

1. $N$ numbered balls are in a bag. $N$ is unknown.
2. Pick a ball uniformly at random, record its number, replace it, shuffle.
3. After $M$ samples, of which we noticed $R$ repeated numbers, how can we estimate the value of $N$?

Clearly, after we've covered the set, only repeats will appear. However, there is a vanishingly small probability we've just missed one.

#### Simplification:

Assume we know $N<n^\star$, which should make it easy to compute $P(N=n|R=r,M=m)$ for all $n<n^\star$.

### Possibly related:

- [probability distribution of coverage of a set after `X` independently, randomly selected members of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32816/22086). Though $N$ is known and coverage is estimated? Here we'd like to estimate $N$.
- [How many random samples needed to pick all elements of set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285716/22086)
  Not the same problem, however.
- [The exact probability of observing x unique elements after sampling with replacement from a set with N elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227556/the-exact-probability-of-observing-x-unique-elements-after-sampling-with-repla?rq=1), A sub-problem? Could we compute the probability $N=n$ by using an answer to this question.

### Application:

Estimating the number of webcomics when I'm pressing "random," assuming random is uniform over the comics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chance of getting a repeat = (M-R)/N which we are going to call a "failure". Call this probability (M-R)/N = (1-P). Now the number of successful draws we have had (without getting a repeat) is M-R. Call this K. Now we just have  a negative binomial distribution with R failures occurring.

The mean of the neg. binomial distribution is the number of successes before the Rth failure. In this case M-R. So M-R = pR/(1-p) with p being defined above.
$$
   \ M-R = (1 - (M-R)/N))R / (M-R)/N
$$
$$
\ = (R - (M-R)R/N) * (N / (M-R)) = NR/(M-R) - R = M - R
$$
$$
\ = M = NR/(M-R) = M^2 - RM = NR --> N = (M^2/R) - M
$$